# Running different test suites with respective exclude tag in robot framework in a single run using run.py?

Tags: python, robotframework

Using the run.py of robot framework I want to achieve the below:

Say we have different test suites which contain N number of test cases, such as:
1. suite_abc
2. suite_xyz

I want to run the above test suites with different exclude tag in a single run.
1. suite_abc --exclude "tag1"
2. suite_xyz --exclude "tag2"

If I call the run.py twice for the above parameters it generates two different reports, but I want the result in one single report and one single run.

Is this possible?

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robot does not directly support what you want. The `--exclude` option applies to the entire test run.

You have at least two ways to solve this problem. First, you can simply run tests twice. You will end up with two reports, as you mentioned in your question. Robot makes it trivial to [combine two reports](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#combining-outputs) into a single report using [rebot](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-rebot). This is the simplest solution. Simply save the results of each run to a different file and then combine them into a single unified report.

The other option is to use the `--prerunmodifier` option (see [Programmatic modification of test data](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-modification-of-test-data)). This lets you provide a function which can define which tests are to run. In your function you can use whatever logic you want to include or exclude tests.

This second method gives you finer grain control, at the expense of having to write a bunch of code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I am using --prerunmodifier. In the documentation ([link] (Programmatic modification of test data), I've used the same code which is used as an example for Exclude tests by name. But I want to exclude test case by tag.
I've coded the part where I extract the tags that are to be excluded for that particular suite. But, Is there a tag match method which I could use in the "_is_excluded" function to match the tags and return True or False?

Comment: I've solved this by using t._setter__tags, through which I was able to access the tags for that particular test case t.